# Ошибка при создании проекта Django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь создать проект django командой django-admin startproject myfirst.
Выдаёт следующую ошибку:
"django-admin" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: `Django` установлен (`pip install django`)? `Python` находится в `PATH`?

Comment: Да, через pip install django. Как путь в PATH прописать, не знаю

Comment: виртуальное окружение устанавливали?

Comment: @Данила Посмотрите, пожалуйста, тут хорошо описано: [How to add Python to Windows PATH](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/). А вообще это можно было сделать автоматически при установке, отметив чекбокс "Add Python to PATH".

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, при установке python-а, вы не нажали галочку 'Ad to PATH'. Система просто не видит ваш python. Самое простое решение - удалить Python и скачать заново, нажав галочку 'Add to Path'.